# jquery autocomplete running ajax but not displaying results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have jquery and jquery ui installed on my site, I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //alert('it ran');
        $('.global_search').autocomplete({ source: "global_search.php", select: function( event, ui){ window.open( ui.item.url ); } });
    });
```

and when I look in the network tab in chrome I see the result
global_search.php?term=54650  ( Note I searched for 54650 )

The response I get from that is

```
{"150000":{"name":"Event: TestRod08.28.2012","value":"Event: TestRod08.28.2012","link":"event_profile.php?event_id=2939"}}
```

Which should display "Event: TestRod08.28.2012" and on click should go to event_profile.php?event_id=2939 but the list never show's up? I have other jquery autocomplete's working on the same page and there list's are showing just fine. Any Idea's?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  $('#test').autocomplete({
    source : function(request, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url : "data.json",
        datatype: 'json'
        }).done(function(data) {
            var results = []

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        results.push({
                                    id : key,
                                    label : value.name,
                    url: value.link
                                });
                    });

            callback(results);
        });
    },
    select : function(event, ui) {
        window.open(ui.item.url);
    }
  });
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7kxw5FuWLOJWh1Mc8qCX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
var options, a;
jQuery(function(){
  options = { serviceUrl:'global_search.php'};
  a = $('.global_search').autocomplete(options);
});
```

You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that my global_search.php was returning a json object instead of a json array ( I had keyed values ) when I removed the key's it works just fine

Thank you everyone for your help